# Issues with injecting markdown module in Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, markdown, showdown

I'm trying to use [this markdown filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-markdown-filter) with angular and I'm having issues with injecting into the module.

```
angular.module("everydayCoding", ['ngRoute', 'markdown'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
          templateUrl: "dev-home.html",
          controller: "ProjectListController",
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: "/"
        })
});
```

I've included it in package.json and ensured it is installed into the node_modules folder.

The error I am getting from the console is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=everydayCoding&p1=E…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4411m @ angular.js:336g @ angular.js:4372fb @ angular.js:4297d @ angular.js:1657yc @ angular.js:1678Xd @ angular.js:1572(anonymous function) @ angular.js:28821j @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211ready @ jquery.js:3417I @ jquery.js:3433
```

Any clues what is causing this issue?

Comment: do you added markdown path inside your index.html .

Comment: check if you have added markdown.js file in your file which is usually index.html

Comment: In the install instructions it only mentions that for bower not npm.  What would i put in there when using npm?

Comment: I think there won't be a problem with angular injector until or unless the file availability of "Markdown" filter. Could you double check ?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, what exactly do you mean by this?